# A number of differences have been observed when using Tails versus TBB. Are these differences normal and part of the design of these packages?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, tails, vidalia, guard, tor-button

A number of differences have been observed when using Tails versus TBB. Are these differences normal and part of the design and implementation of these packages or it maybe something else? Below, please find some of the differences.

Vidalia control panel looks somewhat different in Tails compare to TBB stand-alone Vidalia, in particular, following icons are missing in Tails version of Vidalia.

a. "Stoptor"

b. "Setup Relaying"

c. "Setting"

d. "Exit"

e. Check mark "Show this window on startup"

"Tor button" do not have an active New identity option in Tails

It seems like it is not necessary to activate "html5" in Tails. When one start a video in Tails it start running without user intervention to activate "html5"

The clock does not seem to correspond to user location in Tails.

The TBB version 3.5.2 windows versus Tails version 0.22.1 have been evaluated at this trial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers are to be found in [Tails design documentation](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/):

- [regarding Tor and Vidalia](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/#index28h3),
- [regarding Iceweasel](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/#index40h3),
- [regarding system clock](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/Time_syncing/).